# Is kernel 4.10 hwe going to be patched for Meltdown and Spectre?

Tags: kernel, patch

I am referring to CVE-2017-5753, CVE-2017-5715 and CVE-2017-5754
in relation to Ubuntu 16.04.3 which, if I am not wrong, has now the kernel
4.10 hwe for 64bit platforms.

I've seen the post on Dustin Kirkland blog but, in relation to 16.04, it
only mentions kernel 4.4 and 4.4 hwe. Does anyone knows if the kernel 4.10 
is going to be patched too?

I've also found this page of canonical people related to Meltdown (CVE-2017-5754):

https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2017/CVE-2017-5754.html

but I am not able to understand it. Can someone explain me what package relates to my
installed distribution and the meaning of "needs-triage", "DNE", "Pending" and so on?

Info about my platform:

uname -r
4.10.0-42-generic

lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

Thanks.

Comment: HI Rinzwind, I am not 100% sure, I found articles on ubuntu site that states that 16.04.3 LTS fresh install mounts the 4.10 kernel. I had the 4.8 and it was replaced by 4.10 during an update. I din not make an explicit manual updated, I've allways followed the Updater and now I have the 4.10. See here https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack